# Filter and convert recorded blob to mp3 before sending to backend

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-mediarecorder

I am recording user voice using webrtc.

After the record is completed I am getting the blob content to send it to the backend.

However I want to add some gain and a high passfilter to the recorded audio and converting it to mp3 before I ship it to backend.

I have done some googling, on how to do this but no results so far. So I decided to post here.

```
self.recorder = new RecordRTC(self.clonedStream, {
    type: 'audio/wav',
    audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
    desiredSampRate: 44100,
    numberOfAudioChannels: 2
});
```

submitting to backend:

```
submitRecording() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('recording', this.recorder.getBlob());
    axios.post('/recording', formData).then(response => {
        this.createdRecord = response.data;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: For the high-pass, any reasons you want to do it **after** recording? Or doing it while recording is an option? For the mp3 conversion, you'd have to find a lib able to do it, but it might actually be easier done server-side.

Comment: @Kaiido The app its going to be a campaign thingy, and I dont want to have any performance issues on the server, so I thought I should ship a baked/filtered mp3 file to backend.

Comment: So doing the high-pass on the fly is ok right? You don't need your users to have the ability of fine tuning anything or what else? And for the mp3 conversion, once again, you will need a dedicated lib to do this (there are several, if you search for "lame js" or "mp3 encoding js"), but reconsider if you really need it, because that's a lot of work you'll put on your user's browsers (while they probably do support wav). BTW, avoid asking two questions in the same. Rather open two posts with each question (if you can't find a previous one that does answer it).

Comment: @Kaiido yeah high-pass filter on the fly should be fine. No I just need to get as clear recording as possible as its a singing app. Just came across lame js lets see how that works on safari. Alright I thought two birds with one stone should be fine, but good to know for next time.